# Get root and top level from SQL tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, tree

I have a tree table. And, I am going to get root and top level on this tree.

Help with the solution you can use anything you want

```
declare @disc table (
    id int,
    parent int,
    label varchar(50)
)

insert into @disc
select *
from (
values (1, null,    'q_1'),
       (2, 1,       'a_1_1'),
       (3, 2,       'a_1_1_1'),
       (4, 1,       'a_1_2'),
       (5, null,    'q_5'),
       (6, 5,       'a_5_1'),
       (7, 5,       'a_5_2')
) x (id, parent, label);

1. q_1
   2. a_1_1
      3. a_1_1_1
   4. a_1_2
5. q_5
   6. a_5_1
   7. a_5_2
```

And, my result should be like this:

```
1: 1, null, q_1
2: 2, 1,    a_1_1
3: 5, null, q_5
4: 6, 5,    a_5_1
```

or

```
1: 1, null, q_1
2: 5, null, q_5
3: 2, 1,    a_1_1
4: 6, 5,    a_5_1
```

I only found one way, but I believe there is a better solution:

```
with rec as (
    select id, parent, label,
    row_number() over(order by id) rnk,
    1 lvl
    from @disc
    where parent is null
union all
    select d.id, d.parent, d.label,
    row_number() over(order by d.id) rnk,
    r.lvl + 1
    from rec r
    join @disc d on r.id = d.parent
)
select *
from rec
where parent is null or (rnk = 1 and lvl = 2)
```

Comment: Please share your attempt so far

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you actually want to recurse here.

You can just do a self-join inside an apply.

```sql
select
  row_number() over (order by isnull(c.parent, c.id), c.id),
  c.id,
  c.parent,
  c.label
from @disc p
cross apply (
    select p.id, p.parent, p.label
    union all
    select top 1 c.id, c.parent, c.label
      from @disc c
      where p.id = c.parent
      order by c.id
) c
where p.parent is null;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=acbda1b86247dc46c7b0fd9b088842b8)

Comment: no, not all in rows, should be in diff rows:
root_a
top_a
...
root_b
top_b

Comment: Sorry should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this, the parent value will be null in the root nodes.  The next level down will have a root node as parent.  So ...

```
;with roots as
(
    select id, parent, label
    from @disc
    where parent is null
)
select id, parent, label
from roots
union
select id, parent, label
from @disc
where parent in (select id from roots)
```

Comment: root and one first top level